# Dynamic text highlighting using the rel value from a link on a previous page

Tags: jquery, text, highlight, rel

This might not be possible but I'll throw it out there anyway. I want a way to highlight text so that when you come to a page from a link, jQuery would highlight specific text using the rel attribute from the link (or some other identifier).

For example, let's say I have an event registration site and there is a section for 'Speakers' that will be giving talks at various seminars throughout the event. Then there's a separate page with a calendar for when the speakers will be presenting.

The speaker's name and pic are linked to the calendar which is table based. So far I've only been able to link the speaker's pic and name to a table row on the calendar page using an id in the table row where the respective time slot is contained.

The problem is that sometimes one speaker will be lumped in with other speakers or their table row is too close to the bottom and so the browser window won't align with it exactly. The readability degrades or the name gets lost in the jumble.

I'm trying to figure out how to highlight the speaker's name in the agenda table based on whichever speaker the user clicked on in the 'Speakers' section. This way if the browser window doesn't align the name will be visible and the user won't have to scan for it.

Any suggestions? I appreciate anything, I am relatively green with jQuery. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So first off all you need to make sure that each speaker link has this format:

`<a href="/speaker/12?s=speaker_name>Speaker Name</a>` 
the important part here is:  ***?s=speaker_name***

Once you have that sorted, get to the /speaker/12 page you need to have these variables:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; //will return the full url
var speakerName = pathname.split('s='); //will split the the url into 2 elements
```

Now make sure to have a span with each speaker name that has a class equivalent to Speaker Name and finally a simple jQuery command:

```
$('.'+speakerName[1]).css('background',#F00);
```

Therefore let's say you want to highlight **Tom Sawyer**

1. We'll have the url: http://example.com/speakers?s=Tom_Sawyer Then in
2. this url we'll span tags with class Tom_Sawyer like so: `<span
       class="Tom_Sawyer">Tom_Swayer</span>`
3. Finally we run the jQuery:
           `$('.'+speakerName[1]).css('background',#F00);`